# How to get creation date in sitecore with powershell

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I wrote a script in order to replace the `"$date"` in  release date of many Sitecore items with their creation date (`created`).

I have a problem to get this field from Sitecore.

I tried this:

```sh
$rootItem = Get-Item master:/content
$sourceTemplate = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/.../item 1"
foreach($field in $sourceTemplate.Fields) {
    if (($field -ne $null) -And ($field -like '$date')) {
        $sourceTemplate.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $CreatedDate = .......
        $field.Value = [sitecore.dateutil]::ToIsoDate($CreatedDate)
        $sourceTemplate.Editing.EndEdit()
    }
}
```

I also tried to get this field by `ID` but it doesn't work.

Does someone have an idea please?
Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] the question and elaborate  the  _… it doesn't work_ affirmation (too broad to diagnose). For instance, do you get any error(s)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check Sitecore built-in fields, you need to call `$sourceTemplate.Fields.ReadAll();` first.

You should compare value of the field with `$date` string, not the field itself.

Then just get the string which is stored in the `__Created` field instead of getting date and then formatting it back to ISO date string.

And the last thing - don't call `Editing.BeginEdit()` and `Editing.EndEdit()` mutliple times for the same item - Sitecore runs some havily operations when it's called so make sure you only call it once per every item which needs it.

```
$sourceTemplate = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/home/test"
$sourceTemplate.Fields.ReadAll();
$editing = $false
foreach($field in $sourceTemplate.Fields) {
    if ($field.Value -eq '$date') {
        if (!$editing) {
            $editing = $true
            $sourceTemplate.Editing.BeginEdit();
        }
        $field.Value = $sourceTemplate.Fields["__Created"].Value
    }
}

if ($editing) {
    $edited = $sourceTemplate.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```